# Regular expression match all UK registration plates in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to search a string for all valid UK registration plates. I found the following regular expression which matches both pre/post 2001 UK number plates:

```
^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$
```

How would I go about using that with preg_match_all to return all valid number plates found in a string?

For example:

`This is some random text NV07 ABC This is A0123 ABC some more random text AB08ABC`

Should return:

- NV07 ABC
- AB08ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `^` and `$` (start and end of string) anchors with `\b` (start/end of word) anchors.

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})\b/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: Perfect, that works great.. thanks! I have a lot to learn about Regular Expressions..

Answer (score 0):

From the php's manual:

> int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
>
> Searches subject for all matches to the regular expression given in pattern and puts them >in matches in the order specified by flags.
>
> After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the >last match.

So you need to do:

```
a = array();
preg_match_all ( your_regexp , your_random_string,a)
```

Comment: But that's not going to work here because the regex anchors the match to the start and end of the string.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. I assumed he had a correct regexp while answering.

Comment: His regex is correct, but for a different use case (validation vs. pattern recognition).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the regex has an error which results in it matching ABCdD instead of ABC1D as a number plate.

It's missing the '\' in the first '(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})' which should be '(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})'.

Not a big problem as it only affects plates registered 1983 or earlier with only a single digit.

I would probably update it to:

```
^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{1,3})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{1,3})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?(0[2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$
```

Same as above, this still matches some prefix/suffix letters which are probably invalid, such as IOUZ. And Q as a suffix probably isn't valid either. For others who have found this post and this regex from other sources, it also doesn't match dateless plates (issued 1903-1963) or northern ireland plates (which is also part of the UK), both of which might be an issue if you're concerned with personalised plates. So use with those limitations in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent [gist](https://gist.github.com/danielrbradley/7567269) which has a regex based on the [official guidelines](http://dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk/help/website-usage.html?question=style_reg):

```
(?<Current>^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}$)|(?<Prefix>^[A-Z][0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{3}$)|(?<Suffix>^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]$)|(?<DatelessLongNumberPrefix>^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1,2}$)|(?<DatelessShortNumberPrefix>^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1,3}$)|(?<DatelessLongNumberSuffix>^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,4}$)|(?<DatelessShortNumberSufix>^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,3}$)
```