# Read a number plate using Google Mobile Vision Api

Tags: android, google-vision

I'm currently using Google Mobile Vision API in my Android application.

I need to validate a number plate of a car in real time. Currently my app scans and reads all text that is displayed but I want it to read only the number plate.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any fixed pattern for plate?

Comment: i have started with UK number plates for example UK number plates will be like UK PL8TE or AY 00 000

Comment: If it is always in fixed format, you can use regex pattern as such https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049240/regular-expression-match-all-uk-registration-plates-in-php

Comment: Thanks ,i shall try this regex and keep posted on this